# How do I handle a Complex Multi-Touch Sequence?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The example code "Handling a Complex Multi-Touch Sequence" in the Event Handling section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide provides an incomplete example that assumes the reader knows enough fill-in the blanks. I know enough to know that I don't know enough to do that without some clarification.

In Listing 3-6, I assume `touchBeginPoints` is a member property of type `CFDictionaryRef`. Correct?

In that same example, we're using `malloc()` so I assume we need to call `free()` at some later point. My question is what am I freeing and when? Should I `free()` the individual points in `touchesEnded:`/`touchesCancelled:`? How would I do that? (I assume I need to read up on enumerating `CFDictionaryRef`) Or would I `free(touchBeginPoints);` in my `dealloc:` method?

Finally, in Listing 3-7 there is a `compareAddress:` method. How (and where) would I implement that?

**Update** Found [the answer](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/10/recovering-multiple-touches.html) to the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, touchBeginPoints is a member property of type CFDictionaryRef.
- You wouldn't call free on an instance of CFDictionaryRef, but rather CFRelease. (CoreFoundation's memory management is similar to Objective-C's with explicit reference counting via retain/release semantics.)
- You may want to read "Collection Programming Topics for Core Foundation" to get a stronger feel for CFMutableDictionary. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/CFCollections.html
- As for `free`ing the keys, you probably want to pass in a custom release callback when you create the dictionary. The key release callback is called for each element in the dictionary when the dictionary itself is released. (See the last two parameters to `CFMutableDictionaryCreate` for more.)

`compareAddress:` would look something like:

```
 @interface UITouch (TouchSorting)
 - (NSComparisonResult)compareAddress:(id)obj;
 @end

 @implementation UITouch (TouchSorting)
 - (NSComparisonResult)compareAddress:(id)obj {
     if ((void *)self < (void *)obj) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if ((void *)self == (void *)obj) return NSOrderedSame;
    else return NSOrderedDescending;
 }
 @end
```

Comment: Thanks Art. I'm still pretty shaky on memory management. Is calling `CFDictionaryRemoveValue(touchBeganPoints, touch);` on each touch during `touchesEnded:` not enough to release the memory we've allocated?

Comment: Yes—if I remember correctly any `CFDictionary...` function that removes an entry will trigger the release callback for both the key and value. If there are any entries left when the CFDictionary's retain count is decremented to zero via `CFRelease`, the callbacks are called for those entries.

For this reason, you have to be careful using datatypes that are malloc'ed/free'ed with CFDictionary, as removing an entry will invalidate pointers you may be have elsewhere.

If this behavior doesn't work for your design, you can just pass `NULL` for the callbacks and manage the `free` on your own.